# unit tests for component using utility class with static methods

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular-test

I have component which uses class `LocaleService` and static method of this service `instant()`. `LocaleService` in not injected into component. While testing the component I'm not interested in `LocaleService` internals and I don't want to test it. Thus in `beforeEach` I've added a spy

```
const localeServiceInstantSpy = spyOn(LocaleService, 'instant');
localeServiceInstantSpy.and.callFake(msg => msg);
```

This work well. Now I need to move this spy (and others) to a stub of `LocaleService` and use it in this test and tests of other components using `LocaleService` - there are many of them. What is the most right way to achieve this? How to create reusable LocaleServiceStub?

`\app\utils\locale.service.ts`

```
export class LocaleService {

    public static lang: string;

    private static messages = {
        'user.add': {
            en: 'Add Local User Account',
            de: 'Add Local User Account DE'
        },
        'user.edit': {
            en: 'Edit Local User Account',
            de: 'Edit Local User Account DE'
        }
    };

    public static instant(key: string) {
        return this.messages[key][this.lang];
    }

}
```

Usage in class under test `\app\settings\users\user-form.component.ts`

```
import { LocaleService } from 'app/utils/locale.service';
...
getDialogHeader() {
    return this.isNewUser ? LocaleService.instant('user.add') : LocaleService.instant('user.edit');
}
...
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the situation you're describing. *to a stub of LocaleService* - where is it? *and use it in this test and tests of other components using LocaleService* - what are these tests?

Comment: @estus I've added simplified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static-only classes have code smell in JavaScript. If a class is never instantiated, it's unnecessary.

This is one of the cases that Angular DI is supposed to address. It should be  refactored to a service instead of a class that is used directly.

```
class LocaleService {
    public lang: string;

    private messages = {...};

    public instant(key: string) {
        return this.messages[key][this.lang];
    }
}

...
providers: [LocaleService, ...]
...
```

Then it can be mocked through DI. In order to be reused, a mock can be defined as a provider:

```
const LOCALE_SERVICE_MOCK = {
  provide: LocaleService,
  useFactory: () => ({
    instant: jasmine.createSpy('instant').and.callFake(msg => msg)
  })
};
```

And be specified in test bed:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [LOCALE_SERVICE_MOCK]});
});
```

Or be wrapped with a module:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [LocaleServiceMockModule]});
});
```

In its current state the code can be made DRYer by moving reusable code to a function:

```
function mockLocaleService() {
  const localeServiceInstantSpy = spyOn(LocaleService, 'instant');
  localeServiceInstantSpy.and.callFake(msg => msg);
}
```

And using it where needed:

```
beforeEach(mockLocaleService);
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I know that DI would solve thw case woth mocking injectable service. I use it quite often in other parts of app. This LocaleService is one of few utility classes and it is.easier for developers to use them as static. Similar like in other languages. Otherwise I'd have to inject it.in almost every component. So in every component I'd inject 6 utility classes. I doubt about befefits. This is disturbin the real picture of used services.

Comment: *easier for developers to use them as static* - it's wouldn't be a class but an object. But making it static is a mistake here - because it has a state. It likely should be a singleton, which is a use case for Angular providers. You can learn from other Angular i18n implementations, they have it implemented as a service because this makes sense. That you need to inject it everywhere is easily solved, most times you need to get translations in templates, and this is handled with pipes, no need to access the service directly. https://github.com/ngx-translate/core is close to what you're doing.

Comment: Any way, in its current state (again, that you don't reinstantiate LocaleService is a flaw because `lang` state persists between tests) you can make it DRYer by moving `spyOn(LocaleService, 'instant')` to a function and using it like `beforeEach(mockLocaleService)` where needed.

Comment: You're right - `lang` persists between tests. But I don't want to test `LocaleService` itself but the component. And in a spied function I don't care about `Lang` value. Besides I have other utility classes like formatting. And I use them in .ts also either to prepare data for REST backend or for toast messages of confirmation dialogs. And `LocaleService` is wrapper for service from `@ngx-translate/core` - removed here to make example more simple.

Comment: please write your comment starting with "Any way..." as answer for me to accept.